# How do I check what a txt file contains, and if a fixed number of the last characters match a variable, then delete those who match?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, script, cmd.exe

I have a batch script that need to check what a textfile (`.log` or`.txt`) contains.

When it's done checking, it needs to delete those lines that contain the same configuration of charachters that is defined in another variable.

So, if `var1=abc` then every line that has "abc" as the last (in this case, *three* characters) gets deleted from the text file.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Tom,

I would try findstr.exe with the /v option:

```
findstr /v "text_to_drop" file.txt
```

If you're using powershell, try:

```
PS C:\> Select-String -Path "process.txt" -Pattern "text_to_drop" -NotMatch
```

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490907(v=technet.10) 
and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6

Comment: You will need to use regular expressions to match a string at the end of line, eg `findstr /v /r /c:"%var1%$" file.log`. The output will need to be saved to another file, which is then moved to overwrite the original `file.log`.

Comment: @AFH - or use the `/E` option: `findstr /v /b /c:"%var1%" file.log`. Either way, it only matches lines that end with `\r\n`. If the last line is missing the line terminator, or if unix style lines are used, then this will not work.

Comment: @dbenham - Yes, I forgot about `/e`, which is simpler than using regular expressions; it also won't be affected by RE reserved characters in the match string.